# Change UITableViewCell size gives me an error

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, animation, autolayout

I have a `UIView` in a `static UITableViewCell`. I added a height `constraint` to the `view`. I think, the correct way to animate the change of a `views` height would be like this:

```
self.myViewsHeightConstraint.constant = 100; // Coming from 0 and vice versa
[UIView animateWithDuration:0.3f animations:^{
    [self.view layoutIfNeeded];        
}];
```

I set the `tableView` row height to:

```
tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 40;
self.tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension;
```

Now I need to update the `cells` height. So I think a `begin`/`endUpdate` would be proper. When the `veiw` and the `cell` animate its heights change, they aren't synchronized, so because they don't animate the exact same time, I get the following warning:

```
Unable to simultaneously satisfy constraints.
    Probably at least one of the constraints in the following list is one you don't want. Try this: (1) look at each constraint and try to figure out which you don't expect; (2) find the code that added the unwanted constraint or constraints and fix it. (Note: If you're seeing NSAutoresizingMaskLayoutConstraints that you don't understand, refer to the documentation for the UIView property translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints) 
(
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7f8d62d15670 V:[tagResultTableView:0x7f8d62d901a0(107)]>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7f8d62cea010 tagResultTableView:0x7f8d62d901a0.top == UITableViewCellContentView:0x7f8d62d8fd50.topMargin - 8>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7f8d62cf0760 V:[tagResultTableView:0x7f8d62d901a0]-(8)-[UILabel:0x7f8d62d2e2e0'Limit: Up to 5 tags']>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7f8d62cf0800 UILabel:0x7f8d62d2e2e0'Limit: Up to 5 tags'.bottom == UITableViewCellContentView:0x7f8d62d8fd50.bottomMargin>",
    "<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7f8d62f726d0 'UIView-Encapsulated-Layout-Height' V:[UITableViewCellContentView:0x7f8d62d8fd50(32)]>"
)

Will attempt to recover by breaking constraint 
<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7f8d62d15670 V:[tagResultTableView:0x7f8d62d901a0(107)]>
```

If my logic is correct, how can I animate them the exact same time. Or how can I animate them so I won't get the error?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to make sure the Cell stays static and not change implement this method:

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{}
```

And have a return statement inside that returns the final value of the cell height.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I already set this: `tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 40;
self.tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension; `

Comment: I won't be having only 1 size. It will be 2 sizes. I already tried making an if statement and returning the value if the constraint size is a certain height. That didn't work for me. I got the same error.

Answer (score 0):

You have the height sizing function there, I don't know your exact wants, but if I wanted to change heights I would add an if statement inside the function to test if it's the same as the index as the item you want to make bigger. Refresh your list which will resize the element without causing other issues. I'd also ditch the constraint on the cell view. I don't use size constraints where I plan on resizing the element.